# Using Async Await inside loops

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have encountered a problem where i have to send some JSON data stored in an array to the server.
The problem is loop just run to the next iteration without waiting to get response from the server. 
I Don't want to use Time out Cause i can not preJudge the response time of the server.

```
 async  uploadResponces(responseList) {
var idList = responseList;

for (let i = 0, j = 1; i < idList.length; i++ , j++) {
  var newArray = JSON.parse(idList[i].response)

  await this.apiConnect.postResponseTwo('submitform', newArray).then((data) => {
    self.submitStatus = data;
    alert(JSON.parse(this.submitStatus))
    if (this.submitStatus.status == "success") {
      alert(idList[i].id)
      var topush = JSON.stringify(idList[i].id)
      this.submited.push(idList[i].id)
      if (j == idList.length) {
        alert("submited array" + this.submited)
        this.deleteresponse()
      }
    }
  }).catch((errr)=>alert(JSON.stringify(errr)))
 }
}
```

**the apiconnect.postResponseTwo is-**

```
postResponseTwo(endpoint: string, body: any, reqOpts?: any) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log("post responce function");
  let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Accept,Accept-Language,Authorization,Content-Language,Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Content-Length,Content-Range',

  });

  reqOpts = {
    headers: httpHeaders
  };
  let getURL = this.formUrl + endpoint;
  alert(endpoint + reqOpts);
  alert("url " + getURL);
  alert("passing object " + body);
  this.http.post(getURL, body, reqOpts).map((data) => {
    resolve(data)
    // alert("from server " + JSON.stringify(data));
    //  alert(JSON.stringify(data))

  }, err => {
    alert("error " + JSON.stringify(err));
  })
 });
}
```

here the function postResponse is sending data to the server inside a loop but   `if(j==idList.length){` is not waiting to get the response from server .

Comment: The loop won't "wait" if `.subscribe` doesn't return a promise.

Comment: @FelixKling  .subscribe  is returning a promise but the problem is it takes a little time.

Comment: If it really returns a promise, why does it accept a callback? `await` doesn't care how long the promise takes to resolve.

Comment: Since I don't know what `.post` or `.map` returns, I don't know whether it's a promise or not. But I'm not talking about `.postResponse`, I'm talking about `.subscribe`, since its return value is what you `await`. If `.subscribe` is just a non-standard way of getting the resolved value of a custom promise implementation, you should be doing `let data = await this.apiConnect.postResponse('submitform', newArray);`. But I don't know enough about angular or ionic to know what these methods do.

Comment: to be honest, you should delete all that code and rewrite it from scratch. do NOT mix promises and rx, this gets you nowhere and should only be done in very special cases *if you really know what you are doing*. the code above does not look like you know what you are doing, i even doubt that it sends any request to the server. plus this code is completely different from the one you posted first.

Answer (score 0):

If .subscribe ***really*** returns a promise then you should definitely use Promise.all instead of a loop. All promises are invoked at the same time and run in parallel. Promise.all is resolved only when the last promise in the given array is resolved. Due to parallel execution it's a way better solution than running a loop – unless you depend on execution order, but then you'd need to chain your promises and would not be able to loop anyway.

So, first create an array of promises kind of like this (I have not tested this code, so it might contain typos):

```
// create an array of promises
const responsePromises = map((idItem) => {
  const newArray = JSON.parse(idList[i].response);
  return this.apiConnect.postResponse('submitform', newArray).subscribe((data) =>
  {
     // whatever needs to be processed here
  });
});

// execute promises in parallel either:
Promise.all(responsePromises)
  .then(results => {
    // result handling
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // error handling
  });

// or with async/await but then your enclosing
// function must be async
const results = await Promise.all(responsePromises);
```

Your question was not detailed and sufficiently specified, so my answer might not really match what you've hoped for.

Comment: Don't mix await and then on the same promise like in this line
**`await this.apiConnect.postResponseTwo('submitform', newArray).then((data) => {`**
Either you go with await in which case a result is being returned or you go with then and fetch the result in a closure.

You might do yourself a favour by getting a good book on promises or maybe check out these pages this: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises .

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing async/await and rx. You actually can do that (but you probably should not), since Observables have a `toPromise()` method, and you can await the resulting Promise. But `subscribe()` does NOT return a Promise, it returns a Subscription. A Subscription is used to unsubscribe, is no Promise and thus NOT awaitable.